# PHP: How to use extended interfaces without violating SOLID principles in this case?

Tags: php, oop, interface, liskov-substitution-principle

I'm very sorry for the cryptic title, but I honestly have no idea how to describe it in a short, title-style fashion.

First short version. Simple email confirmation mechanism. One method is sending email with confirmation link. After clicking the link, another controller invokes second method, which verifies token from the URL. Between both actions ConfirmationObject is being stored, with the token and possible other data. After successful confirmation "successHandler" is being used.

Simplified code:

```
interface SuccessHandlerInterface {
    public function success(ConfirmationObjectInterface $object);
}

class EmailTester {
    public function try(ConfirmationObjectInterface $object) {
        // some code
    }

    public function confirm($token) {
        $confirmationObject = $this->repository->findByToken($token);

        $type = $confirmationObject->getType();
        $successHandler = $this->handlersRegistry->getSuccessHandler($type);
        $successHandler->success($confirmationObject);
    }
}
```

Now we are going to use it this way:

```
// Firstly let's implement our own success handler.
class UserRegistrationSuccessHandler implements SuccessHandlerInterface {
    public function success(ConfirmationObjectInterface $object) {
        // Do some stuff on success.
    }
}

// Then let's register this success handler to be available in our `handlersRegistry` object.
$handlersRegistry->addType('user_registration', new UserRegistrationSuccessHandler());

// Now we will extend ConfirmationObjectInterface
interface RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface extends ConfirmationObjectInterface {
    public function getSomeDataGivenOnRegistration();
}

// And at the end, let's try our email

$confirmationObject = new RegistrationConfirmationObject(); // Which implements above interface.
// $confirmationObject->getType() === 'user_registration'

$emailTester->try($confirmationObject);

// Now confirmation link with token is being sent to the given email. If user will click it, below method will be invoked.
$emailTester->confirm($token);
```

The problem now is that I would rather like to have `RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface` in the success handler available, rather than `ConfirmationObjectInterface`.

I know I can do:

```
// Firstly let's implement our own success handler.
class SuccessHandler implements SuccessHandlerInterface {
    public function success(ConfirmationObjectInterface $object) {
        if ($object instanceof RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface) {
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

But it feels bad. This check is pointless as `$object` will always be an instance of `RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface`. How is this design flawed, and how it could be improved?

Comment: I might be getting the wrong end of the stick here but you don't instantiate Interfaces so this sort of thing doesn't make much sense to me : `public function success(ConfirmationObjectInterface $object)` <- is that an Interface or an Object (Class instance)?

Comment: @CD001 It forces the passed object to implement the interface, or php will throw an error.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier does that actually work?

Comment: yeah... it's called type hinting

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I knew you could type hint against, well, types (e.g. classes or abstract classes) never occurred to me to try it with Interfaces... thanks :)

Comment: yeah, coding actually really starts to get interesting when programming to *interfaces*. helps decoupling code, and is generally good for karma ;)

Comment: why there should be  RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface  as interface ? bcoz interface should be created to represent behaviours..

Comment: and how will be  RegistrationConfirmation  in many forms?

Comment: @siddhesh This is the excellent point. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear to me why the Confirmation Objects should implement two interfaces. From what I see here, `RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface` only has one method that returns some data structure, and `ConfirmationObjectInterface` has no methods at all. Is strict type safety really necessary here, especially if you're certain that your custom `SuccessHandler` will receive `RegistrationConfirmationObjectInterface` at all times?

If `ConfirmationObjectInterface` implementations contain no logic and are just data structures, replace them with associative arrays. Otherwise, I would suggest something like this:

```
interface ConfirmationObjectInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData();
}

class RegistrationConfirmationObject implements ConfirmationObjectInterface
{
    public function getData()
    {
        return ['data specific to registration here'];
    }
}

class SomethingElseConfirmationObject implements ConfirmationObjectInterface
{
    public function getData()
    {
        return ['data specific to something else'];
    }
}
```

Since custom handlers are specific to concrete types, they will know what data to expect from `getData()` anyway.

Comment: This is simplified code. `ConfirmationObjectInterface` actually have its own methods like "getType", "getEmail" or "getToken" for example. My current implementation actually depends on associative array precisely because I couldn't solve this problem better, but I started to wonder if there really is no other way :) .

Comment: What does it mean, "better"? Super-strict type safety is not always better. If all methods in `ConfirmationObjectInterface` are getters, these objects are actually data structures and don't really have to be interfaces. The purpose of interfaces is to abstract "how" from "what", and creating extra interfaces for the simplest stuff just adds to the complexity and doesn't solve any real problems.

Comment: This is a good point. I turned this particular project into an exercise of pushing interfaces to the limits, to see when they stop making sense - to improve my understanding of them. I will think about your answer and if it is correct, then I will fully accept it :) .